# D3D11 Sample.Count Change?

Tags: c++, direct3d

heyhey,

let me start with what i am trying todo.

i am drawing a rectangle that can rotate to the backbuffer and i am trying to either antialias it or multisample it.

my issues are the following.
i am in a game that i am getting the d3d swapchain, device, context from etc.
drawing works fine, but the rectangles and lines all look horrible once they start to rotate.
the backbuffer texture returns a sample.count of 1, i dont know if u can change this after the game has inited d3d.

i tried using a texture2d with eg sample count 8 and draw to that, but even if i could, i wouldnt be able to copyresource the texture to the backbuffer.

additionally that texture cant be using sample count 8 cuz i pass it to openvr's setoverlaytexture (different topic, i could prolly copyresource onto a different texture with sample count 1 but the main issue isnt solved, which is me trying to AA the rectangles/lines)

so my question is.

any idea if i can somehow change the samplecount of the backbuffer after d3d is inited?
or are there any other options i could try

Comment: https://walbourn.github.io/care-and-feeding-of-modern-swapchains/

Comment: i am not sure how this should help me

Comment: That blog series covers a number of things including setting up an MSAA render target, resolving to a single sample, and then copying or rendering it to a single sample swap chain. It also explains why there's no reason to set the Sample count of the swapchain to anything but 1.

Comment: i did a bit of testing and got it to render, but with resolvesubresource my issue is that it just overwrites the backbuffer
so if you have the game drawn in the backbuffer, render onto the msaa rendertargetview, and then after drawing call resolvesubresource, i just get a blackscreen with the stuff i have drawn but all the previously drawn stuff is now gone